# Need help finding the problems in a code, and making it more efficient

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I took the time to learn matplotlib in detail, and also did some crash courses to revamp my python skills. I managed to make a program which comibned the two programs, which was what I was trying to do previously. However, now that I've got a program, I can't get it to work.
I ran this program :-

```
import random
import math
import statistics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def approximate_phi_progression(num_points, track_interval=100):
    inside_circle = 0
    phi_progression = []
    for point in range(1, num_points + 1):
        x = random.uniform(0, 1)
        y = random.uniform(0, 1)
        def onephi():
            a = None
            while a is None:
                if random.random() < 0.5:
                    a = 1
                elif onephi() == 1:
                    a = 0
            return a
        # Initialize lists to store phi values for each trial
        phi_approximation = []

        # Perform 100 trials
        for _ in range(num_trials):
            c = 0
            runs = num_points_per_trial
            for _ in range(runs):
                c += onephi()
            phi = 1 / (c / runs)
            phi_approximation.append(phi)
            phi_progression.append(phi_approximation)
    return phi_progression

# Initialize list to store progressions for each trial
method2_progressions = []

num_trials = 100
num_points_per_trial = 10000

# Perform the trials and store progressions
for _ in range(num_trials):
    progression = approximate_phi_progression(num_points_per_trial)
    method2_progressions.append(progression)

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))


def approximate_phi_progression(num_points, track_interval=100):
    inside_circle = 0
    phi_progression = []

    for point in range(1, num_points + 1):
        x = random.uniform(0, 1)
        y = random.uniform(0, 1)
        if x**2 + y**2 <= 1:
            inside_circle += 1
        if point % track_interval == 0:
            phi_squared_approximation = (5/6) * (4 * inside_circle / point)
            phi_approximation = math.sqrt(phi_squared_approximation)
            phi_progression.append(phi_approximation)
    return phi_progression

# Method 1 Progressions
method1_progressions = []

# Perform the trials and store progressions for Method 1
for _ in range(num_trials):
    progression = approximate_phi_progression(num_points_per_trial)
    method1_progressions.append(progression)

# Plotting both methods' progressions on the same graph
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))

# Method 1: Plotting Progressions as lines
for trial_progression in method1_progressions:
    plt.plot([i for i in range(num_trials, num_points_per_trial + 1, num_trials)], trial_progression, alpha=0.5, label='Method 1: Approximation Progression', color="red")

# Assuming method2_progressions is prepared similarly for the Monte Carlo method
for trial_progression in method2_progressions:
    plt.plot([i for i in range(num_trials, num_points_per_trial + 1, num_trials)], trial_progression, alpha=0.5, label='Method 2: Monte Carlo Simulation Progression', color="blue")

# To avoid repeating labels in the legend
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
by_label = dict(zip(labels, handles))
plt.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys(), loc='upper right')

plt.title('Comparison of Phi Value Approximations Across Trials')
plt.xlabel('Number of Points')
plt.ylabel('Phi Value')
plt.show()
```

on python, and I didn't receive any output. The program ran for around 15 mins, and when I stopped it, I got this error :-

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRpE5.png)

I tried everything I could think of, so if anyone has any suggestions/improvements to the code, they would be greatly appreciated. Also are there better ways of plotting using matplotlib?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). FYI keyboard interrupt means you shot the program down, which you did. There's nothing unusual about the message.

Comment: All the error tells us what was doing when you stopped it looks like the last append of the inner most loop.  What did you rry?  Fewer iterations? Tracking iterations? It's rarely a good idea to test a whole script at once.  Test parts and small cases.  Look at intermediate values.  The usual debugging steps!

Answer (score 1):

Do u mean to do so many iterations? As far as I've counted correctly for the first `for` loop, you're doing 1 000 000 000 000 opertaions. So no wonder the code is a bit slow.

```
for _ in range(num_trials):
    print('xd')
    progression = 
    approximate_phi_progression(num_points_per_trial)
    method2_progressions.append(progression)
```

So according to your code you're calling `approximate_phi_progression` function 100 times. Inside the function you're doing the following:

```
    for point in range(1, num_points + 1):
        x = random.uniform(0, 1)
        y = random.uniform(0, 1)

        # Initialize lists to store phi values for each trial
        phi_approximation = []

        # Perform 100 trials
        for _ in range(num_trials):
            c = 0
            runs = num_points_per_trial
            for _ in range(runs):
                c += onephi()
            phi = 1 / (c / runs)
            phi_approximation.append(phi)
            phi_progression.append(phi_approximation)
    return phi_progression
```

So for each one of 10000 points you're performing 100 trials and then again inside each trial you have a loop for `onephi` function. So `onephi` function is called 100 by 10000  by 100 by 10000 = 1 000 000 000 000 of total times, or 10 000 000 000 times by iteration of this `for` loop:

```
for _ in range(num_trials):
    progression = approximate_phi_progression(num_points_per_trial)
    method2_progressions.append(progression)
```

So I tested out `onephi` runtime:

```
import time
s = time.time()
iterations = 1000000
for i in range(iterations):
    a = onephi()
print(f'Finished {iterations} iterations in: ' + str(time.time()-s) +' s')
iterations = 10000000
for i in range(iterations):
    a = onephi()
print(f'Finished {iterations} iterations in: ' + str(time.time()-s) +' s')
iterations = 100000000
for i in range(iterations):
    a = onephi()
print(f'Finished {iterations} iterations in: ' + str(time.time()-s) +' s')
iterations = 10000000000
for i in range(iterations):
    a = onephi()
print(f'Finished {iterations} iterations in: ' + str(time.time()-s) +' s')
```

Output:

```
Finished 1000000 iterations in: 0.4802701473236084 s
Finished 10000000 iterations in: 5.18994927406311 s
Finished 100000000 iterations in: 52.5347626209259 s
```

As for the last one (which is what your code is trying to do 100 times) you can imagine the runtime will be approximately 5000 sec. So all iterations of the first `for` loop will take around 140 hours.